What geometry is preserved by the translation maps on elliptic curves?
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve (over some field).  For any $P \in E$, there is a translation map $T_P: E \to E$ given by $Q \mapsto P+Q$.  This map is rational (i.e. the coordinates of $T_P(Q)$ are rational functions of the coordinates of $Q$) and has rational inverse $T_{-P}$.  So $T_P$ is a birational map.
To what extent does the birationality of the translation maps tell us that the geometry of the curve at one point is the same as its geometry at any other point of the curve?  In particular, I am confused by the following: the intersection multiplicity of $E$ with the tangent at the point $\mathcal O$ at infinity is 3.  So why is it that the intersection multiplicity of the curve with the tangent at $P = T_P (\mathcal O)$ typically 2, not 3?
(My reason for expecting that some geometry be preserved is seeing the analogous setup in Lie groups, where the translation maps are diffeomorphisms).

The translation maps are actually isomorphisms, not just birational maps (this is exactly the same as in the Lie group setting, where the translation maps are isomorphisms). This means any intrinsic geometry at one point is translated in to the same intrinsic geometry at any other point. The problem with your statement is that the intersection multiplicity of the tangent line with the curve at a point is extrinsic - it depends on the embedding.
In particular, for any point $P\in E$, we can embed $E$ in to $\Bbb P^2$ so that under the standard Weierstrass equation, $P$ is the point at infinity and has tangent line which meets the embedded curve with multiplicity three there. But another such embedding where $Q\neq P$ is the point at infinity will almost always have $P$ with a simple tangent (the only exception is when $Q$ is a 3-torsion point under the group law with $P$ as the identity element, and there are only 9 such 3-torsion points).
Via considering everything over $\Bbb C$, you can actually already see this in the realm of Lie groups: you're embedding the Lie group $S^1\times S^1$ in to $\Bbb CP^2$ and the transation maps (mostly) do not extend to automorphisms of the ambient space and don't preserve the intersection multiplicity of the tangent space with the embedded manifold either.
